# How to wrap a gridview around another element in xaml winrt uwp?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I want to achieve something like in the given figure.
[image]

The red part is one Framework element(StackPanel) placed at row 0, column 0.
The orange part is a GridView placed at row 0, column 1. But it wraps only around column 1. How can I wrap it around column 0 too.

Thanks for the Help.

Sample Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="Brown" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel  x:Name="RatingsBreakDownSP" Orientation="Vertical" Background="Cyan" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            </StackPanel>
            <GridView x:Name="reviewsBriefGV" Margin="18,10,18,18" Background="Aqua"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
            </GridView>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Why not to treat this as a whole *GridView* and change only itemtemplate for the first item - which will have suitable properties?

Comment: Okay I'll try that out! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution
- Take the first element of the list and store it in property 
- Bind RatingBoard, FirstElement and then List that skips first element using following relative panel

`

```
<RelativePanel>
        <Rectangle x:Name="RatingBoard" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="FirstElement" RelativePanel.RightOf="RatingBoard" />
        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="myList" RelativePanel.Below="FirstElement" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"/>
    </RelativePanel>
```

`